# Imperative using infinitive verb

Tags: gramática, imperativo, infinitivo

I was wondering if it is possible to ask someone to do something by simply using infinitive form of verb with direct object/indirect object pronoun attached and without using any other words? Or you always have to use imperative form of verb and conjugate it? I am asking because sometimes I think I can hear this infinitive form in movies (translated from English to Spanish), but I am not sure if I heard correctly. In subtitles at the same time I see always conjugated form of verb. But still, can you say the following for example:

"*Matarlo, sin ruido, tengo invitados*" (in subtitles, there was "*Mátenlo, sin ruido, tengo invitados*").

Of course, I am not asking about the following possibility: "*Debes matarlo sin ruido.*"

Comment: I have wondered about this since reading a comment "Ser la energía que queremos atraer". Google translates that into "Be the energy we want to attract" - which sounds imperative. So I too wonder if you can use the infinitive in an imperative way for generic, slogan like statements?

Comment: @Galik To me it doesn't sound imperative, at least not so strong one. As for answering your question, here is a very good link that I went through http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Infinitivo%20-%20otros%20usos.htm#:~:text=En%20el%20habla%20coloquial%2C%20especialmente,Callad%2C%20ni%C3%B1os. In short, it IS possible. Examples: "Sin insultar!" (don't insult me, it's use is more in Spain.)

Comment: @Galik Also from this link there are many more examples, many of them are mostly used in coloquial speech. Even though I admit that this link describes many uses, not only slogan like statements that you asked about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contexts, a dry infinitive could indeed function as an order.  That would be a bit unusual.  It would be a sentence fragment, which in a certain context, could be completing a thought to a certain person who would understand what you're getting at.

There might have been a one-syllable word at the beginning that you didn't catch.  It might have been

> A matarlo etc.

That is another way of telling someone what to do.  For example, "¡A callar, he dicho!", "A parir Madres Latinas, A parir más guerrilleros, etc." (see https://www.albumcancionyletra.com/himno-a-las-madres-latinoamericanas_de_jose-de-molina___122510.aspx).

Comment: To the downvoter: I would be glad of the opportunity to learn from my mistakes.  Would you care to leave some feedback to help me understand the downvote?

Comment: Something I have often wondered. On a browser, say, if you click on the menu, it might say "cerrar pestaña". In English I would understand the equivalent as a command, i.e. "Close the tab, browser!" But in Spanish, does it sound that way, or more like "tab closure" or "tab closing" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You may have heard wrong.  What you might have heard is *"Matadlo, sin ruido, tengo invitados"*  This is equivalent to *"Mátenlo, sin ruido, tengo invitados"*.  "Matadlo" is how you conjugate the verb with the plural pronoun "Vosotros".  "Matarlo" does not make sense in this context.