# Imperativo como una combinación de "en" + el sustantivo infinitivo

Tags: gramática

Observé varios ejemplos en algunas películas, donde la frase siguiente se usó para ordenar:

"*¡En marcha!*"

También en la cadena [Imperative using infinitive verb](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32432/23475) ya aclaré el uso de "a" + el verbo infinitivo.

Preguntas:

1. Supongo que esto ("¡En marcha!") es el caso de omitir el verbo "poner". De lo contrario, sería como "¡ponte en marcha!" y yo sé que esta frase sí existe. ¿Lo entiendo correcto?
2. Por lo general, ¿cómo debería usar esta forma como imperativo? Por ejemplo, vi una vez la frase "¡ponte en trabajo!". ¿Se puede decir como "¡En trabajo!"?
3. ¿Cuál es la diferencia en significado entre "¡en marcha!" y "¡a trabajar!"? Supongo que no hay diferencias.

P.s. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“En marcha” es una frase hecha, fija. Es razonable pensar que proviene de una expresión como “¡Ponte en marcha!” de donde se ha elidido (omitido) el verbo en imperativo, pero los hablantes no necesariamente la usamos pensando en ese origen. “En marcha” se puede usar con “ponerse” pero también con “estar”.

No hay un principio general por el cual se pueda usar “en” + sustantivo de acción. “En trabajo” no es una frase reconocida, por lo cual no es correcto decir “¡En trabajo!”, sino que la expresión correcta sería “¡A trabajar!”.

Expresiones similares y válidas a “en marcha” son “en funcionamiento” y “en movimiento”.

En principio la idea de “¡en marcha!” y “¡a trabajar!” es la misma: ambas expresiones son órdenes o incitaciones a moverse o a trabajar, respectivamente. El significado no es el mismo. “(Ponerse) en marcha” significa empezar a moverse o funcionar; “(ponerse) a trabajar” significa empezar a trabajar.